# Ext Js How to add combobox to specific cell in Grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I'm using Ext Js v6.2, In my application table constructed with ext js grid, I want to add combobox to specific cell **[DEMO IMAGE ATTACHED]**, when I try to add combobox entire cell changes to combobox, But I need specific cell to be combobox. Here my code, I've searched in documentation and other stuff it doesn't help.please solve the problem.

```
        Ext.define('OtherCharges1', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: [
                {name: 'name', mapping: 'name'},
                {name: 'age', mapping: 'age'},
                {name: 'marks', mapping: 'marks'},
                {name: 'rate', mapping: 'rate'}
            ]
        });
        var newData1 = [
            {name: "Freight"},
            {name: "Insurance" },
            {name: " Addl Chrg(High Sea)"},
            {name: "Revenue Deposit on"}
        ]
        var gridStore3 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            model: 'OtherCharges1',
            data: newData1
        });
        var otherStore1 = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            cls: 'custom-grid',
            id: 'OtherId',
            store: gridStore3,
            stripeRows: true,
            width: '100%',
            collapsible: false,
            enableColumnMove: false,
            columnLines: true,
            sortableColumns: false,
            enableColumnHide: false,
            enableColumnResize: false,
            enableRowHeightSync: true,
            columns:
                    [
                        {
                            header: "",
                            dataIndex: 'name',
                            flex: 1

                        },
                        {
                            editor: {
                                xtype: 'textfield',
                                selectOnFocus: true
                            },
                            dataIndex: '',
                            flex: .5,
                            sortable: true,
                            hideable: false,
                        },
                        {
                            editor: {
                                xtype: 'textfield',
                                selectOnFocus: true
                            },
                            dataIndex: 'age',
                            flex: .5,
                            sortable: true,
                            hideable: false,
                        },
                        {
                            editor: {
                                xtype: 'textfield',
                                selectOnFocus: true
                            },
                            dataIndex: 'marks',
                            flex: .5,
                            sortable: true,
                            hideable: false,
                        },
                        {
                            editor: {
                                xtype: 'textfield',
                                selectOnFocus: true
                            },
                            dataIndex: 'rate',
                            flex: .5,
                            sortable: true,
                            hideable: false,
                        }],
            selType: 'cellmodel',
            plugins: [
                Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
                    clicksToEdit: 1
                })]
        });
```

[image: Ext Js Grid]

Comment: To clarify, you want to be ale to edit only certain cells in a particular column?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Already all the cell can be edited, my concern is change specific cell has combobox.

Comment: Right, only some cells in the column, not all cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable editing the grid in a specific cell you need to edit the `beforeedit` event. Create a validation to make sure you are editing the cell you want.

In this case you will only edit the cell in column 1 and row 1.

```
grid.on('beforeedit', function(editor, e) {
  if (e.colIdx === 1 && e.rowIdx === 1)
  {
      return true;
  }
  else 
  {
      return false;
  }
});
```

Remember that the ExtJS grid starts at 0.
[See this example fidlle.](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1res&view/editor)